# Sequelize prevent cache

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have always used mongoose in my applications, however I am using sequelize in a specific application.

however I am facing problems with caching on the client side.

for example, in my list of categories, there is the function of editing, when I edit and save, the client side application calls the listing again, to show the updated data.

this works very well with mongoose, but with sequelize the cache does not let the data be updated on screen.

I leave below an example of how I am doing the listing and editing on the server side

```
const get = (req, res, next) => {
    categoriesModel.findAll({})
    .then(data => res.json({
        status: true,
        data: data
    }))
    .catch(error => res.json({
        status: false,
        data: [],
        msg: error
    }))
}

const put = (req, res, next) => {
    categoriesModel.update({
        title: req.body.title,
        active: req.body.active
    },
    {
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(data => res.json({
        status: true,
        data: data,
        msg: 'Success!'
    }))
    .catch(error => res.json({
        status: false,
        data: [],
        msg: error
    }))
}
```

Comment: What caching are you referring to? The browser's caching? Sequelize doesn't come with a cache out of the box, does it?

Comment: @cbr the browser's cache, in the chrome developer console, it shows (disk cache) in the network tab

Comment: Are you setting some caching related headers elsewhere in your backend? Try explicitly disabling the cache for your API routes, i.e. `res.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); res.set("Pragma", "no-cache"); res.set("Expires", 0);`

Comment: What response headers are you getting for that response in your browser's developer tools' Network tab?

Comment: Yes, it solved! I added max-age=0 in the "Cache-Control", thx!

Comment: Great. Add it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following header rules

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0")
    res.set("Pragma", "no-cache")
    res.set("Expires", 0)
    next()
})
```